# PHP move_uploaded_file() error?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I using following code and it is successfully uploading files on my local machine. It is showing "Successfully uploaded" on my local machine.

```
// Upload file
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . "myFile.txt" );

if( $moved ) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded";         
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded";
}
```

But when I used this code on my online server then it is not uploading file and just showing message "Not uploaded".

How can I know that what is the problem and how can I get the actual problem to display to the user ?

Comment: Do you have the images folder on the web server?  Is the folder read only, or can you write to is also?

Comment: Any PHP generated error message? Btw you don't need to use $moved, you can put the move_uploaded_file command into the statement.

Comment: @all: This is the problem that it is not showing any error/warning on server. Images folder exists and I can upload files in this folder using FileZilla.

Comment: Because FileZilla can write this directory it didn't means your web server can write too.

Comment: No. You should read an error message and fix the problem.

Comment: @Col: How to read the message it is not showing any message. I have no rights on server. My customer is just updating server and he said that he has given the 777 rights to images folder :)

Comment: "How" is another question. that can be answered. but you have to understand very basic rule: without error message you are blind, deaf and mute. Your only desire and efforts should be to get error message. Am I clear enough?

Comment: A programmer should not trust. Not to a customer who said something, nor a volunteer from SO, nor himself. But only in error message a programmer can trust.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check that the web server has permissions to write to the "images/" directory

Comment: I can upload files in this folder manually using FileZilla, it means it has the rights. Any other possibility ?

Comment: FileZilla doesn't prove that the web server has permissions. The web server will most likely run under a different user than you are. To make sure it has permissions, just set the permissions to 777, then test. This should prove if it's a permission issue or something else.

Comment: What happend when the 2 mb files are uploaded but 5 mb file is not uploaded? both that files are the pdf type of the file. so how can I get the exact error message  from the server. So we can know what the exact issue.

Comment: So I have checked phpinfo function where upload_max_filesize is 2mb so I think that can be issue so I will increase the size and check again

Comment: FileZilla is an FTP client, the webserver is the user under wich apache is running....  whoami();

Answer (score 78):

Edit the code to be as follows:

```
// Upload file
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . "myFile.txt" );

if( $moved ) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded";         
} else {
  echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];
}
```

It will give you one of the following error code values 1 to 8:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE = 
>   Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE = 
>   Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL = 
>   Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE = 
>   Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR = 
>   Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE = 
>   Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
>
> UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION = 
>   Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help.

Comment: What was Error 5?

Comment: @Dan According to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) , **Error 5** is not documented. Personally I haven't encountered it.

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/';

if (is_dir($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir)) {
    // do upload logic here
} else {
    echo 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.';
}
```

This will instantly flag any file permission errors.

Comment: Says as 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.' How it is solved, please explain?

Comment: @SignoffTeamz Either make the upload directory writeable, or create it if it doesn’t exist.

Comment: The usage of chmod/chown within Linux for file permissions is not covered enough in web development tutorials. I've found that 776 (not best practice, most like 775) solves most issues with permissions.  Use the -R option with chmod to ensure permissions are passed to the directory and the files in the directory. If using apache2 Chown should have www-data as the owner group and your username as the owner. You should add yourself to the user group www-data, so that permissions from the server are inherited within that folder for testing purposes.

Answer (score 19):

> How can I know that what is the problem

Easy. Refer to the error log of the webserver.

> how can I get the actual problem to display to the user ?

**NEVER** do it.
An average user will unerstand nothing of this error.
A malicious user should get no feedback, especially in a form of very informative error message.

Just show a page with excuses.

If you don't have access to the server's error log, your task become more complicated.
There are several ways to get in touch with error messages.

To display error messages on screen you can add these lines to the code

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or to make custom error logfile

```
ini_set('log_errors',1);
ini_set('error_log','/absolute/path/tp/log_file');
```

and there are some other ways.
but you must understand that without actual error message you can't move. It's hard to be blind in the dark

Comment: Well, it's fine to show errors on a development site. It's not always possible to redirect errors to a log file (e.g. on shared hosting).

Comment: @Pekka we are talking of a live one atm. And, honestly, such a hosting should be abandoned immediately.

Answer (score 7):

`move_uploaded_file()` will return:

1. `FALSE` if file name is invalid
2. `FALSE` and `issue a warning` in the error log if the apache process does not have read/write permissions to source or destination directories

**PHP Error Log**

My php error log was at: `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and had these errors:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/robot.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/mysite/mohealth.php on line 78
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpsKD2Qm' to 'images/robot.jpg' in /var/www/html/mysite/mohealth.php on line 78

`move_uploaded_file()` tries to move files from a temporary directory to a destination directory. When apache process tried to move files, it could not read the temporary or write to the destination dir.

1. **Find which user is running Apache (Web Server)**
   Check which user is running the apache service by this command: `ps aux | grep httpd`. The first column is the user name.
2. **Check Read Permission at Temporary Dir:** Your can find the path to your temp dir by calling `echo sys_get_tmp_dir();` in a php page. Then on the command line, issue `ls -ld /tmp/temporary-dir` to see if the apache user has access to read here
3. **Check Write Permission at Destination Dir:** issue `ls -ld /var/www/html/destination-directory` to see if the apache user has access to write here
4. Add permissions as necessary using `chown` or `chgrp`
5. **Restart Apache** using `sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: How to check the user in windows?

Comment: The problem was solved with the keyword "source". Look at that:  "move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE and issue a warning in the error log if the apache process does not have read/write permissions to 'source' or destination directories." So it is not enough to give all permission to your project directory and also should give all permission to the source file's location.

Answer (score 2):

Do you checks that file is uploaded ok ? Maybe you exceeded max_post_size, or max_upload_filesize. When login using FileZilla you are copying files as you, when uploading by PHP wiritng this file is from user that runs apache (for exaplme www-data), try to put chmod 755 for images.

Answer (score 1):

or run suexec and never have to change permissions again.

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` search for **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size**. I had the same problem and the solution was to change these values to a value greater than the file size.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your `form` tag have this attribute:

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Thesis/images/';
$profic = uniqid(rand()).$_FILES["pic"]["name"]; 

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile.$profic);
    if($moved)
    {
        echo "sucess";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On virtual hosting check your `disk quota`.

if quota exceed, `move_uploaded_file` return error.

PS : I've been looking for this for a long time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check permission "images/" directory

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very obscure and annoying cause of error 6.
After goofing around with some NFS mounted volumes, uploads started failing. 
Problem resolved by restarting services

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
systemctl restart httpd.service
```