# Objective-C and PHP File Upload and Moving

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, networking, mknetworkkit

I have having quite a bit of trouble trying to get an uploaded file into the right directory, very similar to: [PHP move_uploaded_file() error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error) however, everything really seems to be fine with the code and permissions. I'm using this tutorial for the Objective-C portion: http://www.michaelroling.com/post/upload-an-image-using-objective-c and the complete implementation of the app and PHP script are written below. The issue however may be that the Objective-C is never actually transmitting the image.  Let me know if you need more information. The PHP returns:

**The file upload is reported as successful, however it does not actually upload the jpeg.**

```
- (IBAction)shareWithFriends:(id)sender
{

if (imageView.image != nil)
{
    NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.1);

    self.fileUploadClient = [[fileUploadClient alloc] initWithHostName:@"shipstudent.com" customHeaderFields:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *postParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Animal" forKey:@"appID"];

    self.fileOperation = [self.fileUploadClient postData:postParameters path:@"/animal/pictureuploads.php"];

    [self.fileOperation addData:image forKey:@"userfl" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"upload.jpg"];

    [self.fileOperation addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *operation)
    {

        NSLog(@"%@",[operation responseString]);
    }

     errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *errorOperation, NSError *error)
     {

         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];

         [alert show];

     }];

    [self.fileUploadClient enqueueOperation:self.fileOperation];

}
else
{

}
```

}

PHP:

```
<?php


if(!empty($_POST)) 
{

    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/appphotos';

$file = basename($_FILES['userfl']['upload.jpg']);

$uploadfile = $directory . $file;

    $randomPhotoID = md5(rand() * time());

echo "file=".$file;

//where the error resides
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfl']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       echo 'successful';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'unsuccessful';

}

}
else
{
    echo('Empty post data');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen from the error, you're attempting to write to nowhere. Your `$uploaddir` variable is never set, and `$file` will always be null, so you're telling it to write to `$uploadfile = null . null`, try this instead:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {

    $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/appphotos/';
    // $file = basename($_FILES['userfl']['upload.jpg']);
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfl']['name']);
    // $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
    $uploadfile = $directory . $file;
    $randomPhotoID = md5(rand() * time());

    echo 'file=' . $file;

    //where the error resides
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfl']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo 'successful';
    } else {
        echo 'unsuccessful';
    }

} else {
    echo 'empty post data' ;
}
```

Comment: I found that out after some debugging however, it will not write the image even though it says it is successful.  Also, the directory will not write anything unless I do: $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/appphotos'; instead of $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'appphotos/';

Comment: That's because `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` doesn't end with a directory separator, so use `/appphotos/` instead. Also, is the directory 777? If not, run `chmod 777 /path/to/dir/here/appphotos` from the command line.

Comment: If I used the / after the appphotos folder it reutrns the error:  
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/tmp/php0dqQSS' to '/home/shipstud/public_html/appphotos/' in <b>/home/shipstud/public_html/animal/pictureuploads.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />

Comment: Either the filename isn't being provided, or there are permission issues.