# PHP move uploaded file returns false but it's OK

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm sending pics from my Android App to the server which has this php code:

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

After the uploading is finished, the picture is in the expected folder but the echo were "fail". It is important to know the correct echo, why could be possible the echo returns as failed?

Comment: Possibly `uploads/` is not writable by the server user?

Comment: maybe your file is exists in dir before uploading?

Comment: @mcklayin nope, the dir is initially empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP move\_uploaded\_file() error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error)

Comment: @syck the folder has rwxrwxrwx  permissions.

Comment: Did you check the servers error log? Is error_reporting set to display warnings and notices?

Comment: Try replacing file path (second line) with this: `$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file_path . pathinfo( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Comment: The file in `uploads/` could come from a _different_ request - you should look at your logs, and add appropriate logging to your code to determine what's happening. Unrelated but is your android app really parsing the response of your upload as a string?!? That's pretty fragile - maybe the response is really `Notice undefined whatever blah blahsuccess' and the problem to fix is that, or some similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$file = $_FILES['fileup']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'];
$target_dir = "uploads/".basename($file);
if($file!="")
{  
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$target_dir))
    {
        $fileErr = "Image Upload Success";
    }
    else
    {
        $filer = "Image Upload Not Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your code with changes fileup by uploaded_file and putting echos inside the if. The result was I get no echos and the pic was correctly uploaded humm :/

Comment: Sorry, I've realized that the pic was already uploaded at the moment get the echo from the php url. Tomorrow I will check the android code again, now it's late.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the error return value to display the type of error like:

```
<?php
$errors=array(
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE',
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE',
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL',
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE',
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR',
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE',
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    =>  'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION'
);

$file_path = "uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path ) ) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    $error=$errors[ $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] ];
    echo "fail:" . $error;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android programmers should have to use

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
String s = convertInputStreamToString(is);
```

Now s return success. convertInputStreamToString is my own method but everyone can figure out to write it.
Suggestion by @mcklayin was correct.