# Simple File upload code in PHP

Tags: php

This issue might have been discussed multiple times but I wanted a simple PHP script to upload a file, without any separate action file and without any checks. Below is my written code:-

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="upload file" name="submit">
  </form>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>FILE UPLOAD</p><br>'; 
 $tgt_dir = "uploads/";
 $tgt_file = $tgt_dir.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
 echo "<br>TARGET FILE= ".$tgt_file;
 //$filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
 echo "<br>FILE NAME FROM VARIABLE:- ".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 if(file_exists("uploads/".$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]))
    { echo "<br>file exists, try with another name"; }
 else   {   
         echo "<br>STARTING UPLOAD PROCESS<br>";
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $tgt_file))
        { echo "<br>File UPLOADED:- ".$tgt_file; }

          else  { echo "<br>ERROR WHILE UPLOADING FILE<br>"; }
    }
 }
?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I saved it in **/var/www/html/phps/** location. But everytime I try to upload the file, I get **ERROR WHILE UPLOADING FILE** error. What am I doing wrong here. P.S. I have no previous experience of PHP, I just started with bits & pieces from internet.

Thanks
kriss

Comment: permissions, likely.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error

Comment: @yivi, great. Thanks. It is working now. Damn, it didn't click before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP move\_uploaded\_file() error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/"; 
$target_file = $target_dir .
basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} 
else {
       echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

I hope that this thing will work and this is what you are in need of.

Comment: Thanks, but the form is missing so can't really upload using just this code. BTW I sorted out the permissions problem & my code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$image = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$tempname = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempname, "foldername/$image");?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it - why does it solve the given problem?