# Why PHP move_uploaded_file doesn't works?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I know I have permissions in both folders because using the same method from a different php script I can perform the operation.

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"],'../files/documents/'.$nom_file)`

I've already checked that the source file exists and that ../files/documents/ also exists and $nom_file is a correct name for the new file.

Why it doesn't works?

Also, when I try to display the result of the move_uploaded_file function, the result is empty. Why? Isn't supposed to be true or false?

Comment: What do you see when you enable warnings?

Comment: [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3501749/6521116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP move\_uploaded\_file() error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3501749/6521116)

Comment: try with absolute path