# Failed multipart upload using retrofit 2

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit

I'm new at retrofit and I want to upload using retrofit 2. Every uploading the file the response is

> Fail Upload

from the php but if I'm using Postman it always success.

Below is my code.

**Main Activity**

```
File zip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.zip");
            RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-file"), zip);
            MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", zip.getName(), reqBody);

            ApiServices api = RetroClient.getApiServices();
            Call<ResponseApiModel> upload = api.fileUpload(filePart);
            upload.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseApiModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseApiModel> call, Response<ResponseApiModel> response) {

                    if (response.body().getCode().equals("1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseApiModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("RETRO", "ON FAILURE : " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

**Api Services**

```
@Multipart
@POST("getzip.php")
Call<ResponseApiModel> fileUpload (@Part MultipartBody.Part File);
```

**PHP Code**

```
$part = "./upload/";
$filename = rand(9,9999).".zip";

$res = array();
$code = "";
$message = "";


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
        $destinationfile = $part.$filename;
        $data = $_FILES['file'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($data['tmp_name'], $destinationfile)) { 
            $code = 1;
            $message = "Success Upload";
        }else {
            $code = 0;
            $message = "Fail Upload";
            }
    }else{
        $code = 0;
        $message = "request error";
    }
}else
{
    $code = 0;
    $message = "Request Not Vaild";
}

$res['code'] = $code;
$res['message'] = $message;

echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: instead of returning "Fail Upload" dump the file $_FILES['file'] check the dump..  try `echo json_encode($_FILES['file'])` in php file  in else part `$message = "Fail Upload";` and log the message in  Android app inside onResponse for better error handling use response.code == 200 inside onResponse.

Comment: Read this blog, https://mobikul.com/uploading-number-files-using-retrofit-multipart-request/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PHP but I know Retrofit. Here is how I do it and works perfectly, this uploads the whole folder, you may change accordingly to handle your files.

You need to use Multipart Format.

Here is a code sample below:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("sync/contact/image")
    Call<Response> ImageUpload(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

    @Multipart
    @POST("sync/image")
    Call<ResponseBody> MultiImageUpload(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> mapFileAndName);


 public static HashMap<String, RequestBody> GetAllImage(Context context) {
        File files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/.ELMEX");
        File[] filesArray = files.listFiles();
        List<File> listOfNames = Arrays.asList(filesArray);
        HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>(listOfNames.size());
        RequestBody file = null;

        for (int i = 0, size = listOfNames.size(); i < size; i++) {
            file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), listOfNames.get(i));
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + listOfNames.get(i).getName() + ".jpg", file);
            file = null;
        }

        return  map;
    }


 HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = UtilImage.GetAllImage(context);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = Retro.getRetroWS().MultiImageUpload(map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the suggestions given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error). Check out all the answers and comments, not just the accepted answer, because there are some really good ideas on what could be wrong, as well as good ideas on how to debug the problem.