# Move file after upload in a specific folder?

Tags: php, html

I have a little problem here, probably caused by a typo or something. I ve tried to make this piece of code works for two hours now...

### What I basically want to be able to do:

- The user navigates to the `/Home/` folder
- He selects and uploads a file
- When clicking on submit, without knowing, the user passes to the PHP script a POST request containing the `/Home/` value (the folder the user is currently in).
- The script does some spooky magicals spells and transfers the uploaded file to /Home/.

The last magical part is the one that bugs me tho... The files uploads and gets stored in the script s folder if I dont specify a folder name, dont get me wrong. The sad thing is, if I do, the script throws me errors talking about "Impossibility to move the concerned file to /Home/." (The part im troubleshooting has the comment "BUGGY PART")

```html
<?php
$source = $_FILES["file-upload"]["tmp_name"];
$uplace = $_POST['place'];
$destination = $_FILES["file-upload"]["name"];
$error = "";

// CHECK IF FILE ALREADY EXIST
if (file_exists($destination)) {
  $error = "<h1>Erreur</h1><br><p>Le fichier ".$destination." existe déja.";
}

// BUGGY PART
if ($error == "") {
  if (!move_uploaded_file($source, "/Home/" . "$destination")) {
    $error = "<h1>Erreur</h1><br><p>Impossible de bouger le fichier $source vers ".$destination."</p>";
  }
}

// ERROR OR OK?
if ($error == "") {
 echo "<h1>Upload complété.</h1>"; 
 echo "<p>Informations du fichier uploadé:</p>";
 echo "<ul>";
 echo "<li>Nom: ".pathinfo($destination)['filename']."</li>";
 echo "<li>Format: ".pathinfo($destination)['extension']."</li>";
 echo "<li>Taille: ".formatSizeUnits(filesize($destination))."</li>";
 echo "<li>Storé sur: ".$uplace."</li>";
 echo "</ul>";
 }
else { echo $error; }
```

How can I move the freshly uploaded file from the temporary folder to /Home/ ?

(Just for reference:

The script is located at: /Home/RESSOURCES/upload.php

I want to upload files to: /Home/

All of my folders are chmod-ed to 777 recursively.
)

Cheers.

Comment: You can get the reason for the move failure by checking the value of `$_FILES["file-upload"]["error"]`. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904093/1790644) for more details.

Comment: The outputted error code is "0"... Isnt 0 supposed to mean "It works"? @Matt

Comment: Then you will need to find the log generated by the webserver itself and look there.

Comment: Sorry I took the last error from the log by accident Heres the real error: `[Mon Jan 14 21:49:05.408522 2019] [:error] [pid 942] [client ::1:46928] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/Home/snap21662.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/Home/RESSOURCES/upload.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost:81/Home/
[Mon Jan 14 21:49:05.408851 2019] [:error] [pid 942] [client ::1:46928] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpG2Hd1C' to '/Home/snap21662.png' in /var/www/html/Home/RESSOURCES/upload.php on line 14, referer: http://localhost:81/Home/`

Comment: Ill get back to ya if I need more help. Cheers :) @MattClark

Comment: There you go - you are trying to move the file into a directory which does not exist.

Comment: you need the full server path to /Home

Comment: Ohh I get it now... Many thanks ill remember next time! :)